# Why is $i e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}=e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}} $?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I am doing some matrix multiplication, and at one point it is stated that,

$$ \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{pmatrix}
 \ = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}\end{pmatrix}$$

but how does $i e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}=e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}} $?
I have tried taking Euler's formula but I can only get it to reduce down $$ \frac{-i-1}{\sqrt{2}i}$$

I have also tried converting to polar form, but I just really can't see how these two are equivalent. It must be correct, since when I type it into Wolfram alpha it does show that the angle is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Also, apologies for the strange brackets on the matrices, I am still a bit new on TeX notation!

Comment: *note*: $e^{\pi i }=-1$

Comment: MathJax tip: Use the `bmatrix` environment, instead of the `array` environment for matrices. While `array` gives you more flexibility (such as adjust the alignment of individual columns), `bmatrix` is much easier, looks good, and gives the square brackets to boot (also compare and contrast to `pmatrix`, `vmatrix`, `Vmatrix`, and just `matrix`). Example: `\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{bmatrix}` produces $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{bmatrix}$ (without having to worry about `\left[` and `\right]`).

Comment: By using Euler's Identity , $ie^{\frac{\pi  i}{4}}=i\sqrt{i}$ and , RHS will be $e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}=\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\right)^3=(\sqrt{i})^3=i\sqrt{i}$

Answer (score 3):

This is the whole process of solving:

$$ie^{i\frac\pi4}=e^{i\frac\pi2}e^{i\frac\pi4}=e^{i\frac{3\pi}4}$$

Answer (score 1):

As $i^4 = 1$, $i$ represents a rotation by $2 \pi/4 = \pi/2$ radians counterclockwise . Similarly, $e^{i \pi/4}$ represents a rotation by another $\pi/4$ radians multiplying represents the composition of the two transformations,  for a total of $3\pi/4$ radians or $e^{3i \pi/4}$.

Remember that $e^{it}$ is a rotation of $t$ radians due to Euler's identity $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to see the rectangular way of solving it (though I highly recommend you just use polar form), we know that $e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ and we want to prove that $ie^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}=e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}=\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. We know that
$$ie^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$$
$$=i\cdot \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\frac{i+i^2}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}$$